# Charge 2 - Stripe form fields not showing

Tags: templating, plugin-charge, stripe

I just had a fresh install of Charge 2 and my Craft version is Craft CMS 2.6.2989. However as long as I have `{{craft.charge.setPaymentOptions()}}` in my template, all my form fields disappear and show up again after I remove this line.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Bookings" | t %}

{% set entry = craft.entries.section('bookings').first %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="[ grid ] island">
        <div class="[ grid__item desk-seven-twelfths ]">
            {% if entry.heading | length %}
                <h1 class="brand-color">{{ entry.heading }}</h1>
            {% endif %}

            {% if entry.featureImage | length %}
                <img src="{{ entry.featureImage.first.url('halfWidth') }}" alt="{{ entry.Title }}" class="push--bottom">
            {% endif %}

            {% if entry.introText | length %}
                <div class="lede">{{ entry.introText }}</div>
            {% endif %}

            {% if entry.body | length %}
                {% include '_partials/_body' %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="[ grid__item desk-one-third push--desk-one-twelfth ]">
            <div class="island ui-background--light">
                <h3 class="push-half--bottom text--center ui-color--dark">{{ "Make a Payment" | t }}</h3>

                <hr class="rule rule--double">

                <form id="charge-form" method="post" data-publicKey="{{ craft.charge.publicKey }}">
                    {% set chargeOptions = {'planAmount' : 99} %}
                    {{craft.charge.setPaymentOptions(chargeOptions)}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="charge/charge"/>

                    <label for="customerEmail">Receipt Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="customerEmail" value="{{ currentUser ? currentUser.email }}" id="customerEmail"/>

                    <label for="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" data-stripe="number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" id="cardNumber"/>

                    <label for="cardExpiry">Card Expiry</label>
                    <input type="text" data-stripe="exp" placeholder="mm / yy" id="cardExpiry"/>

                    <label for="cardCvc">Card CVC</label>
                    <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="123" id="cardCvc"/>
                </form> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% includeJsResource('charge/js/jquery.charge.js') %}
    {% includeJsResource('charge/js/stripe_v2.min.js') %}
    {% includejs %}
        $(this).charge();
    {% endincludejs %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

I can't see what's wrong with my setup...

Comment: Looks like `{{craft.charge.setPaymentOptions()}}` returns a 500 and the page just half rendered, stopped at this line

Comment: There is something wrong with function

 ```public function encode($arr)
    {
        return base64_encode(craft()->security->encrypt(serialize($arr)));
    }```

Comment: Never mind, I figured out. After looking into the source code of the encrypt function, it calls `mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size` and because my vagrant box didn't have `php5-mcrypt` installed, it failed there.
To fix it:
`apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Leon.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source code of the encrypt function, the `craft.charge.setPaymentOptions()` function calls `mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size` and because my vagrant box (ubuntu 14.04) didn't have `php5-mcrypt` installed, it failed there.

To fix it: run `apt-get install php5-mcrypt && sudo php5enmod mcrypt`.